# Angular 2, @ngtools/webpack, AOT

Tags: angular, webpack-2, angular2-aot

I'm trying to use AOT in Angular 2 using webpack and @ngtools/webpack.

I don't have any error with the compilation, but when I open the site on the browser I get a console error:

`No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'`

My AotPlugin on webpack configuration is this:

```
new AotPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',
    entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module.ts#AppModule')
})
```

My app.module.ts is:

```
@NgModule({
bootstrap: [ App ],
imports: [ // import Angular's modules
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES),
    SharedModule
],
declarations: [
    App,
    HomeComponent,
],
providers: providers
})
export class AppModule {}
```

and my main.browser.ts:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";

const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

My tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noEmitHelpers": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "lib": ["es6", "dom"],
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "baseUrl": "./src",
    "paths": [],
    "types": [
      "hammerjs",
      "jasmine",
      "node",
      "protractor",
      "selenium-webdriver",
      "source-map",
      "webpack"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist"
  ],
  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useWebpackText": true
  },
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false,
  "atom": { "rewriteTsconfig": false },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "dist",
    "entryModule": "src/app/app.module#AppModule"
  }
}
```

Webpack.config.js:

```
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV) {
  case 'prod':
  case 'production':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.prod')({env: 'production'});
    break;
  case 'test':
  case 'testing':
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.test')({env: 'test'});
    break;
  case 'dev':
  case 'development':
  default:
    module.exports = require('./config/webpack.dev')({env: 'development'});
}
```

My /config/webpack.prod.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge'); // used to merge webpack configs
    const commonConfig = require('./webpack.common.js').config; // the settings that are common to prod and dev
const hashName = require('./random-hash.js')(); // the settings that are common to prod and dev

    /**
     * Webpack Plugins
     */
    const ProvidePlugin = require('webpack/lib/ProvidePlugin');
const DefinePlugin = require('webpack/lib/DefinePlugin');
const NormalModuleReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/NormalModuleReplacementPlugin');
const IgnorePlugin = require('webpack/lib/IgnorePlugin');
const DedupePlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/DedupePlugin');
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('webpack/lib/optimize/UglifyJsPlugin');

/**
 * Webpack Constants
 */
const ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV = process.env.ENV = 'production';
const HOST = process.env.HOST || 'localhost';
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const METADATA = webpackMerge(require('./webpack.common.js').metadata, {
    host: HOST,
    port: PORT,
    ENV: ENV
});

module.exports = function (env) {
    return webpackMerge(commonConfig({ env: ENV }), {

        devtool: 'hidden-source-map',

        output:{
            path: helpers.root('dist'),
            filename: '[name].bundle.js?ver='+ hashName,
            sourceMapFilename: '../maps/' + '[name].map?ver='+ hashName,
            chunkFilename: '[id].chunk.js?ver='+ hashName
        },


        plugins: [
            // NOTE: when adding more properties make sure you include them in custom-typings.d.ts
            new DefinePlugin({
                'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                'process.env': {
                    'ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV),
                    'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(METADATA.ENV)
                }
            }),
            new webpack.LoaderOptionsPlugin({
                optons: {
                    debug: false,
                    htmlLoader: {
                        minimize: true,
                        removeAttributeQuotes: false,
                        caseSensitive: true,
                        customAttrSurround: [
                            [/#/, /(?:)/],
                            [/\*/, /(?:)/],
                            [/\[?\(?/, /(?:)/]
                            ],
                            customAttrAssign: [/\)?\]?=/]
                    },
                    tslint: {
                        emitErrors: true,
                        failOnHint: true,
                        resourcePath: 'src'
                    },
                    postLoaders: [
                        {
                            test: /\.js$/,
                            loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                            query: {
                                search: 'var sourceMappingUrl = extractSourceMappingUrl\\(cssText\\);',
                                    replace: 'var sourceMappingUrl = "";',
                                        flags: 'g'
                            }
                        }
                    ],
                    preLoaders: [
                    {
                        test: /\.ts$/,
                        loader: 'string-replace-loader',
                        query: {
                            search: '(System|SystemJS)(.*[\\n\\r]\\s*\\.|\\.)import\\((.+)\\)',
                            replace: '$1.import($3).then(mod => (mod.__esModule && mod.default) ? mod.default : mod)',
                            flags: 'g'
                        },
                        include: [helpers.root('src')]
                    },
                    {
                        test: /\.ts$/,
                        loader: 'tslint-loader',
                        options: {
                            configFile: 'tslint.json'
                        },
                        exclude: [/\.(spec|e2e)\.ts$/]
                    }

                ]
                }
            })
        ],

        node: {
            global: true,
            crypto: 'empty',
            process: false,
            module: false,
            clearImmediate: false,
            setImmediate: false
        }

    });
};
```

And config/webpack.common.js:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const helpers = require('./helpers');

/*
 * Webpack Plugins
 */
// problem with copy-webpack-plugin
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const ForkCheckerPlugin = require('awesome-typescript-loader').ForkCheckerPlugin;
const HtmlElementsPlugin = require('./html-elements-plugin');
const AssetsPlugin = require('assets-webpack-plugin');
const ContextReplacementPlugin = require('webpack/lib/ContextReplacementPlugin');
const AotPlugin = require('@ngtools/webpack').AotPlugin;

/*
 * Webpack Constants
 */
/*
 * Static metadata for index.html
 *
 * See: (custom attribute)
 */
const METADATA = {
    title: '',
    baseUrl: '/',
    isDevServer: helpers.isWebpackDevServer()
};

/*
 * Webpack configuration
 *
 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cli
 */
module.exports = {
    metadata: METADATA,
    config: function(options) {
        isProd = options.env === 'production';
        return {

            /*
             * Cache generated modules and chunks to improve performance for multiple incremental builds.
             * This is enabled by default in watch mode.
             * You can pass false to disable it.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#cache
             */
            //cache: false,

            /*
             * The entry point for the bundle
             * Our Angular.js app
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#entry
             */
            entry: {

                'polyfills': './src/polyfills.browser.ts',
                'vendor':    './src/vendor.browser.ts',
                'main':      './src/main.browser.ts'

            },
            // output: {
            //   // Make sure to use [name] or [id] in output.filename
            //   //  when using multiple entry points
            //   //    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
            //   //  chunkFilename: "[id].bundle.js"
            //   publicPath: "https://d3ohoc4mai6ihm.cloudfront.net"
            // },

            /*
             * Options affecting the resolving of modules.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve
             */
            resolve: {

                /*
                 * An array of extensions that should be used to resolve modules.
                 *
                 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#resolve-extensions
                 */
                extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.json'],

                // An array of directory names to be resolved to the current directory
                modules: [helpers.root('src'), 'node_modules'],

            },

            /*
             * Options affecting the normal modules.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module
             */
            module: {

                /*
                 * An array of automatically applied loaders.
                 *
                 * IMPORTANT: The loaders here are resolved relative to the resource which they are applied to.
                 * This means they are not resolved relative to the configuration file.
                 *
                 * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-loaders
                 */
                loaders: [

                    /* Ahead of time plugin */
                    {
                        test: /\.ts$/,
                        loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
                    },

                    /*
                     * Json loader support for *.json files.
                     *
                     * See: https://github.com/webpack/json-loader
                     */
                    {
                        test: /\.json$/,
                        loader: 'json-loader'
                    },

                    /*
                     * to string and css loader support for *.css files
                     * Returns file content as string
                     *
                     */
                    {
                        test: /\.css$/,
                        loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
                    },

                    /* Raw loader support for *.html
                     * Returns file content as string
                     *
                     * See: https://github.com/webpack/raw-loader
                     */
                    {
                        test: /\.html$/,
                        loader: 'raw-loader',
                        exclude: [helpers.root('src/index.html')]
                    },

                    /* File loader for supporting images, for example, in CSS files.
                     */
                    {
                        test: /\.(jpg|png|gif)$/,
                        loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000000000'
                    },

                    // Support for SCSS as raw text
                    {
                        test: /\.scss$/,
                        loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']
                    },

                    //{ test: /\.scss$/, loaders: ['style', 'css', 'postcss', 'sass'] },

                    {test: /\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|svg)$/, loader: 'url-loader?limit=100000000000'}

                ],


            },

            /*
             * Add additional plugins to the compiler.
             *
             * See: http://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#plugins
             */
            plugins: [
                new AssetsPlugin({
                    path: helpers.root('dist'),
                    filename: 'webpack-assets.json',
                    prettyPrint: true
                }),

                /*
                 * Plugin: ForkCheckerPlugin
                 * Description: Do type checking in a separate process, so webpack don't need to wait.
                 *
                 * See: https://github.com/s-panferov/awesome-typescript-loader#forkchecker-boolean-defaultfalse
                 */
                new ForkCheckerPlugin(),
                /*
                 * Plugin: CommonsChunkPlugin
                 * Description: Shares common code between the pages.
                 * It identifies common modules and put them into a commons chunk.
                 *
                 * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#commonschunkplugin
                 * See: https://github.com/webpack/docs/wiki/optimization#multi-page-app
                 */
                new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
                    name: ['polyfills', 'vendor'].reverse()
                }),

                /**
                 * Plugin: ContextReplacementPlugin
                 * Description: Provides context to Angular's use of System.import
                 *
                 * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#contextreplacementplugin
                 * See: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11580
                 */
                new ContextReplacementPlugin(
                    // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
                    /angular(\\|\/)core(\\|\/)(esm(\\|\/)src|src)(\\|\/)linker/,
                    helpers.root('src') // location of your src
                ),
                new ContextReplacementPlugin(
                    // The (\\|\/) piece accounts for path separators in *nix and Windows
                    /moment[\/\\]locale$/, /en-gb/
                ),

                /*
                 * Plugin: CopyWebpackPlugin
                 * Description: Copy files and directories in webpack.
                 *
                 * Copies project static assets.
                 *
                 * See: https://www.npmjs.com/package/copy-webpack-plugin
                 */
                new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
                    from: 'src/assets',
                    to: 'assets'
                }]),

                /*
                 * Plugin: HtmlWebpackPlugin
                 * Description: Simplifies creation of HTML files to serve your webpack bundles.
                 * This is especially useful for webpack bundles that include a hash in the filename
                 * which changes every compilation.
                 *
                 * See: https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin
                 */
                new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
                    template: 'src/index.html',
                    chunksSortMode: 'dependency'
                }),

                /*
                 * Plugin: HtmlHeadConfigPlugin
                 * Description: Generate html tags based on javascript maps.
                 *
                 * If a publicPath is set in the webpack output configuration, it will be automatically added to
                 * href attributes, you can disable that by adding a "=href": false property.
                 * You can also enable it to other attribute by settings "=attName": true.
                 *
                 * The configuration supplied is map between a location (key) and an element definition object (value)
                 * The location (key) is then exported to the template under then htmlElements property in webpack configuration.
                 *
                 * Example:
                 *  Adding this plugin configuration
                 *  new HtmlElementsPlugin({
                     *    headTags: { ... }
                     *  })
                 *
                 *  Means we can use it in the template like this:
                 *  <%= webpackConfig.htmlElements.headTags %>
                 *
                 * Dependencies: HtmlWebpackPlugin
                 */
                new HtmlElementsPlugin({
                    headTags: require('./head-config.common')
                }),

                /* Ahead of time compilation plugin */
                new AotPlugin({
                    tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',
                    entryModule: helpers.root('src', 'app', 'app.module.ts#AppModule')
                })
            ],

            /*
             * Include polyfills or mocks for various node stuff
             * Description: Node configuration
             *
             * See: https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#node
             */
            node: {
                global: 'window',
                crypto: 'empty',
                process: true,
                module: false,
                clearImmediate: false,
                setImmediate: false
            }

        };
    }
}
```

Complete error trace:

```
Uncaught Error: No NgModule metadata found for 'AppModule'.
    at NgModuleResolver.resolve (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:18969) [<root>]
    at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:18172) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._loadModules (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:50582) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndComponents (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:50542) [<root>]
    at JitCompiler.compileModuleAsync (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:50508) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_._bootstrapModuleWithZone (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:39236) [<root>]
    at PlatformRef_.bootstrapModule (vendor.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:39211) [<root>]
    at Object.<anonymous> (main.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:34315) [<root>]
    at __webpack_require__ (polyfills.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:53) [<root>]
    at webpackJsonpCallback (polyfills.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5…:24) [<root>]
    at :8080/main.bundle.js?ver=d1084b5dbd73943cc778978401608960:1:1 [<root>]
```

I don't really know what's going on. I really appreciate your time and you help.

Comment: I currently have the same issue, still trying to find what's causing it. However, if I change `const platform = platformBrowserDynamic();
platform.bootstrapModule(AppModule);` to a single line with `platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)`, the generated output works but does no longer use tree shaking.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know if it helps, but I had similar problem. I'm guessing you are using some kind of boilerplate because you have this `helpers.root` function.

**First of all** try to change this part:

```
new AotPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',
    entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module.ts#AppModule')
})
```

to this (**adding `helpers.root` part to `tsconfig.json` file**):

```
new AotPlugin({
    tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),
    entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module.ts#AppModule')
})
```

**Second of all** double check your `tsconfig.json` to be configured to AoT compilation. This is my `tsconfig-aot.json` which I',m using in one of my Angular 2 projects:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "sourceRoot": ".",
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },

  "awesomeTypescriptLoaderOptions": {
    "useWebpackText": true,
    "forkChecker": true,
    "useCache": true
  },

  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit" : true
  }
}
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Sadly, that didn't fixed my problem, and I'm getting the same error. And... I thought that using @ngtools/webpack you could have AOT without change the code.

Comment: no, you should modify some parts. ``tsconfig.json`` file should look like in my answer. ``"module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",`` and ``"angularCompilerOptions"`` are the most important settings. Also, if you are using ngtools, you should not change ``main.browser.ts``. I recommend you to read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111198/webpack-typescript-and-angular2-with-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation)

Comment: also, you need to proceed in webpack ``.ts`` files with ngtools. Can I see you webpack.config.js file? And what boilerplate do you use?

Comment: I updated my question with the files you requested. Thanks for your effort!

Comment: @Lucha I don't see that you changed ``tsConfigPath: 'tsconfig.json',`` to ``tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig.json'),``. And one more thing: when you building your script using ``webpack.prod.config.js`` file, right?

Comment: @Lucha I have noticed one more thins. Here ``entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module.ts#AppModule')`` change to ``entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module#AppModule')`` without ``.ts``

Comment: Yes, both alternatives gives me the same error, with helpers.root, without it, and this .ts and without it.

Comment: Ok, pasted already on my original post. Thanks for the time and the patience.

Answer (score 0):

Try rolling back to ngtools/webpack version 1.2.4 there are issues with the path resolution in later versions related to this issue [5329](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5329).