# Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript

I searched here, [Angular 2, @ngtools/webpack, AOT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42651383/angular-2-ngtools-webpack-aot), but does not worked for me. 
I ran the `npm install` command.
What i'm doing is that i'm creating a new Angular 2 project. and while I run `ng serve --open` then I got the below error.

> could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack"
>   package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be
>   installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Below is the stacktrace:

```
`C:\Users\jang\Desktop\kendoGrid>ng serve --open
Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
Error: Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2" package to be installed.Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jang\Desktop\kendoGrid\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\index.js:18:11)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jang\Desktop\kendoGrid\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\webpack-config.js:3:19)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)

C:\Users\jang\Desktop\kendoGrid>ng version`
```

Comment: npm install typescript@latest --save-dev

Comment: Thanks @gyc! it worked :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the sake of not having answers in the comments section, here the error is self explanatory:

> The "@ngtools/webpack" package requires a local "typescript@^2.0.2"
>   package to be installed

So webpack needs typescript and you just have to install it.

```
npm install typescript@latest --save-dev
```

Comment: sure as it should be to help others like me.

Comment: it does not help at all

Answer (score 0):

Yea this error also comes up when you upgrade "@angular/cli".
Except that you can't fix it by merely installing typescript again.

This is how I fixed it:

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
npm uninstall --save-dev @angular/cli 
npm install -g @angular/cli@latest
npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```