# throw new Error('Could not find local "typescript" package.')

Tags: angular

I am getting this error when I upgraded angular from version 5.2 to 11. I have typescript installed in the package.json file. But when i run the app, I keep getting the error :throw new Error('Could not find local "typescript" package.')

I have also referred to the below issue but that did not help me.

[Could not find local "typescript" package.The "@ngtools/webpack" package Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47770769/could-not-find-local-typescript-package-the-ngtools-webpack-package-angular)

Comment: How did you run the update? You may need to update from 5 to latest minor in 5, then to 6 ... but always i would suggest to update ng update tool, instead of running the update within your package manager because there are migration to be applied.

Comment: Could you please suggest the right approach to upgrade the app from version 5.2 to the latest version of 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to create a new project to upgrade the app. just copied the source file and the then upgraded the dependencies. also changed the code in the components where ever needed. i was able to upgrade my app successfully.