# How configure Nginx to serve an Angular 2 + webpack 2 + AOT app

Tags: angular, webpack-2, angular2-aot

Normally using JIT compiler I am able to build my distribution and serve it on production with a simple Nginx configuration:

```
server {
   listen       8082;
   server_name  127.0.0.1;
   root /path/to/my/dist;

   location / {
       try_files $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
   }
}
```

But now I am trying to configure Nginx to serve an AOT compiled version following [this configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39111198/webpack-typescript-and-angular2-with-ahead-of-time-aot-compilation/40009194#answer-40009194). 
The AOT compiled files are located in the **/aot** directory, which contains the folders **node_modules**, **src** and all the **ngFactory.ts** files generated.

My question is, how can this app be served by Nginx? Usually when I create bundles with Webpack I just need to serve the **index.html, polyfills, app, vendor** and the **assets**, but here looks like I have the whole project structure.